# how to specify <text> is not a tag in html

Tags: html, rich-text-editor

If I have a string

```
str = "<" + "some text" + ">";
```

How would I output this to a rich text editor, with the desire to also display the '<' and '>' surrounding the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of < and >, respectively.

```
str = "&lt;" + "some text" + "&gt;"
```